# How to use React.memo with react-redux connect?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Does anyone know how to wrap a React component with `React.memo` when one is using the `connect` function from react-redux?

For example, how would you modify the following?

```
let Button = (props: Props) => (
  <button onClick={props.click}>{props.value}</button>
);

Button = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(Button);
```

I've tried:

```
let Button = React.memo((props: Props) => (
  <button onClick={props.click}>{props.value}</button>
));

Button = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(Button);
```

However, the function returned by `connect` expects a component to be passed so it errors with:

> Uncaught Error: You must pass a component to the function returned by
>   connect. Instead received {"compare":null}

Comment: What about `React.memo(connect(...)(Button))`?

Comment: @putvande Yeah, This code can work, but the second parameter of memo can not get the object that returned by mapStateToProps ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Same issue here. Fixed by upgrading `react-redux` to version 5.1.0.

Comment: So which format is more efficient `connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(React.memo(Button));` or `let Button = React.memo((props: Props) => (
  <button onClick={props.click}>{props.value}</button>
));` or is the no real difference?

Comment: @Ryc you don't want to use memo on a connected component: the props given to the component will not change whereas the redux state may change and require an update...

Answer (score 23):

`React.memo` is nothing but a HOC, so you can just use:

**Without memo:**

```
connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(Button);
```

**With memo:**

```
connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(React.memo(Button));
```

**And even wrap to connect:** (This should be the solution with connect)

```
React.memo(
  connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
  )(Button)
);
```

Like we do with `withRouter`: `withRouter(connect(...)())`

Comment: Why did you say that the last solution should be the correct one ? For me, it seems that `React.memo` should be the closest HOC to the component itself, because it should be the one to receive the store and to check if the re-rendering is needed, whereas in the last solution, it only checks the re-rendering with the props directly passed to the component, not the store.

Comment: But should you use `memo` when connecting a Redux component if that component *only* use Redux props (and not parent-inherited ones)? probably not since Redux already does shallow comparison automatically.

Comment: @arnaudambro, I think having `memo` inside or out of `connect` is dependent on the situation. Redux's `connect` has its own options for determining the equality of the props created from the store so you might use React.memo on the outside to use its equality check for the direct props and rely on the `connect` options for the equality check of the `store` props. If React.memo's equality checks work for the direct props AND the store props, then it makes sense to put it inside of `connect`

Answer (score 7):

Your solution should work (I didn't try copy-pasted like that), but you also have to update `react-redux` to the latest version.

By the way, I think the proper implementation of `React.memo` within many HOC would be to be the closest to the component itself : the goal of `React.memo` is to check if all the new props received by the component are the same as the last props. If any HOC transforms or adds any props to the component - which `connect` does by mapping the Redux store to the props, `React.memo` should be aware of it in order to decide wether or not to update the component.

So I would go for something like that :

```
//import what you need to import

const Component = props => <div>{/* do what you need to do here */}</div>

export default compose(
  connect(mapStateToProps, dispatchToProps),
  /* any other HOC*/
  React.memo
)(Component);
```

Answer (score 0):

#### **[Codesandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/vm05zynql0)**

As the error message says, you need to pass a component to the returned function from `connect`.
*( which means the second pair of () in  `connect()()` )*

As `React.Memo` returns a component, pass it into the second function of `connect`.
Here's how you can do this.

```
export const MemoizedDemoComponent = connect(mapStateToProps)(React.memo(DemoComponent);
```

---

Demo component:

```
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

const DemoComponent = props => (
  <div>
    <p>My demo component fueled by: {props.fuel}!</p>
    <p>Redux: {props.state}</p>
  </div>
);

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  state: "your redux state..."
});

// create a version that only renders on prop changes
export const MemoizedDemoComponent = connect(mapStateToProps)(
  React.memo(DemoComponent)
);
```

For a working example check also [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vm05zynql0).

Answer (score 0):

For someone who want to know why `react-redux` throw this error.

For me, I used version `5.0.7`, `react-redux/src/components/connectAdvanced.js` line: 92

```
invariant(
  typeof WrappedComponent == 'function',
  `You must pass a component to the function returned by ` +
  `${methodName}. Instead received ${JSON.stringify(WrappedComponent)}`
);
```

After upgrading this code is changed to :

```
invariant(
  isValidElementType(WrappedComponent),
  `You must pass a component to the function returned by ` +
  `${methodName}. Instead received ${JSON.stringify(WrappedComponent)}`
);
```

How to check the `WrappedComponent` is changed to `isValidElementType(WrappedComponent)` which is exposed by `react-is`

So, yarn update `react-redux` to the version that mentioned by @Maxime Chéramy at least